# Replacing items in list with multiple "keys" in one index

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I am trying to change my list items to their actual values.  For example, this is how my data looks right now:

```
data = [
['student1', '"answer 1"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 3"'],
['student2', '"answer 10"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 3", "answer 4"']
```

As seen in the last item in data[1], there can be multiple responses to a singular question.  My code right now is this:

```
def answer_replace(data):
    replaced_data = []  
    for element in data:
        replaced_element = []
        for index, item in enumerate(element):
            print (index)
            print (item)
            if index in answer_replacement:
                replaced_element.append(answer_replacement[index].get(item, item))
            else:  # no replacement available for this index
                replaced_element.append(item)
            print (replaced_element)
        replaced_data.append(replaced_element)
    return replaced_data
```

It works fine except for the cases with multiple answers.  I was trying to use re.sub, but couldn't get it to work. (The answers I want to change the values to are stored in the dictionary answer_replacement)

Comment: So what exactly should happen to `'"answer 3", "answer 4"'`? Should it become `'"replacement 1", "replacement 2"'`? And which index would be used to look up their replacement? Would they both share the index 3?

Comment: @Rawing Yes, it should be '"replacement 1, "replacement 2"', but your second question is part of my confusion with this problem.  I'm not sure which what index to use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to remove "answer" from the student's response. You can try this:

```
data = [ ['student1', "answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"], ['student2', "answer 10", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"]]

student_data = {i[0]:[b.replace("answer", "replacement") for b in i[1:]] for i in data}
```

Output:

```
{'student2': ['replacement 10', 'replacement 2', 'replacement 3', 'replacement 4'], 'student1': ['replacement 1', 'replacement 2', 'replacement 3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out a couple minutes after posting this.  Go figure.  Here's what I did:

```
def answer_replace(data):
    replaced_data = []  
    for element in data:
        replaced_element = []
        for index, item in enumerate(element):
            if index == 5 or index == 7 or index == 8 or index == 10 or index == 12 or index == 15:
                newitem = item.split(',')
                temp = []
                for item in newitem:
                    item = item.strip()
                    temp.append(re.sub(item, answer_replacement[index][item], item))
                replaced_element.append(temp)
            elif index in answer_replacement:
                replaced_element.append(answer_replacement[index].get(item, item))
            else:  # no replacement available for this index
                replaced_element.append(item)
        replaced_data.append(replaced_element)
    return replaced_data
```